# Adding indexes to model fields in Django with migrations

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-migrations, django-2.1

I am trying to add indexes on model fields using `Field.db_index` for an app that has migrations. Looking at [Django's documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.db_index) all I need to do is to set `db_index=True`:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField()
    last_name = models.CharField(db_index=True)
```

and then I first tried the new Django's Migration:

```
./manage.py makemigrations app-name
```

but Migration does not seem to notice the change and does not add the sql command for creating an index. So I tried `django-admin.py` as explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-sqlindexes):

```
django-admin.py sqlindexes app-name
```

But that does not print the sql command either and it exits with the following error:

```
CommandError: App 'app-name' has migrations. Only the sqlmigrate and sqlflush commands can be used when an app has migrations.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, I managed to create the indexes using `Meta.index_together`. It is not the cleanest way, since I am not actually indexing multiple fields together but it works with `makemigrations`:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        index_together = [['last_name']]
    first_name = models.CharField()
    last_name = models.CharField()
```

Now `makemigrations` does make a new migration:

```
./manage.py makemigrations app-name

>>Migrations for 'app-name':
>>  0005_auto_20140929_1540.py:
>>    - Alter index_together for Person (1 constraint(s))
```

And the corresponding sql command is actually `CREATE INDEX`.

```
./manage.py sqlmigrate app-name 0005_auto_20140929_1540

>>BEGIN;
>>CREATE INDEX app-name_person_last_name_7...4_idx ON `app-name_person` (`last_name`);
>>COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 25):

This problem still exists in django2.1.
I solved it by using the [indexes Meta option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#indexes). This is a bit cleaner than the `index_together` solution.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField()
    last_name = models.CharField()

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['last_name']),
        ]
```

Answer (score 9):

You can do this explicitly in your migration using Django's [AddIndex](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/migration-operations/#addindex) and [Index](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/indexes/#index-options) classes.

First create an empty migration with `manage.py makemigrations --empty` and then simply fill it out as follows:

```
from django.db import migrations
from django.db.models.indexes import Index
from django.db.migrations import AddIndex


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('app_name', 'ref_to_previous_migration'),
    ]

    operations = [
        AddIndex('ModelName', Index(fields=['field_name'], name='my_index'))
    ]
```

You can use options on the `Index` class to specify fields, add a name, and do special custom things like index only part of the table, etc. Check the doc links above.