# Django rest framework ModelSerializer runs too slowly

Tags: django, performance, django-rest-framework

We want to provide an api for our django project,so we use drf (django rest framework).
we use ModelSerializer which provides a shortcut that lets you automatically create a Serializer class with fields that correspond to the Model fields.
Our problem is it runs very slowly.In other word,process of serialization takes about 40 second until retrieving the response.

How we can reduce this delay?
VIEW

```
class MyObjViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    pagination_class = LargeResultsSetPagination

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = MyObj.objects.all().order_by('time')
        return queryset

    serializer_class = MyObjSerializer
```

My Obj Model

```
class MyObj(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    type = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    user = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='myobj')
```

MyObj User Model

```
class User(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=80)
```

my Obj serializer

```
class MyObjSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = MyObj
        fields = ('id', 'type', 'time', 'user')
```

My problem is when i want to retrieve list of my objs, its take about to 40 second!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Optimizing db queries in Django Rest Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26593312/optimizing-db-queries-in-django-rest-framework)

Comment: @KevinBrown  : No this is not my problem!

Comment: Are you sure? It seems very similar (foreignkey with another model) its also explained in here https://ses4j.github.io/2015/11/23/optimizing-slow-django-rest-framework-performance/

Comment: I still welcome new answers to this question, I believe Django serializers are slow. :/ And it's not a DB problem.

Answer (score 8):

Actualy, it is a real problem of drf.
If you have a lot of objects returned by queryset then you have to do few steps:
 1. Check that you use `many=True`, it will produce significant performance improvement.
 2. Avoid `ModelSerializer` on huge objects sets. In fact, worth idea is to avoid any kind of `rest_framework.Serializer`
 3. Try to use `serpy` library for serializing. But you shouldn't forget that it is not fully compatible with `rest_framework.Serializer`.
 4. Use `.values()` and `DictSerializer`. It will give you BIG speed up of serializing.
 5. Do not forget about indexes in your database.
 6. Use such powerful things as `prefetch_related` and `select_related` while working with `ForeignKey`.
 7. The last way is to use simple `dict`. Otherwise, I didn't get appreciable result: only 10% versus `serpy` with `DictSerializer`.

I had a case when I have to serialize many objects (about 3-5k), overhead from drf serializer was at least 2,5 seconds (without sql's time). After optimizing I got about ~200-300 ms.

I hope, drf's developers will do some perfomance-improvements in framework.

Answer (score 1):

Man, don't use "MyObj.objects.all().order_by('time')",

If you has above tens of hundreds of datas, then just get all and order by time,
it would takes so long......

"that is not the seriallizer's problem, that is an order problem." 
you can limit the time you search, use:

1、gt：bigger then

```
now = datetime.datetime.now()
#yesterday
start = now – datetime.timedelta(hours=23, minutes=59, seconds=59)
a=yourobject.objects .filter(youdatetimcolumn__gt=start)
```

2、gte：bigger or equl then

```
a=yourobject.objects .filter(youdatetimcolumn__gte=start)
```

3、lt：littler then

```
a=yourobject.objects .filter(youdatetimcolumn__lt=start)
```

4、lte：littler or equal then

```
a=yourobject.objects .filter(youdatetimcolumn__lte=start)
```

5、range： a range of time

```
start_date = datetime.date(2005, 1, 1)
end_date = datetime.date(2005, 3, 31)
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__range=(start_date, end_date))
```

6、year： one of the years

```
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__year=2005)
```

7、month：one of the months

```
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__month=12)
```

8、day：a day

```
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__day=3)
```

9、week_day： a weekday

```
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__week_day=2)
```

source: https://www.cnblogs.com/linjiqin/p/3821914.html

If you need to use get.all, then just not use "order_by_time", in normal situation, not use order_by_time can make your requset faster, you just need to order it after get these datas.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem of the serializer, the problem its on the query.

You are getting all the objects, I assume there is a big number of them because of the pagination and also you want them all ordered by time. The problem is that the Model definition has no hint for the database to create a index on the time field.

Try to add the hint to create an index in the database and the speed will rise.

```
  class MyObj(models.Model):
      id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
      time = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
      type = models.CharField(max_length=5)
      user = models.ForeignKey('User', related_name='myobj')
```

Comment: Thanks, i did it but the problem still exist!

Comment: Take a look at this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26109184/adding-indexes-to-model-fields-in-django-1-7-with-migrations about migrations but as you say the query time looks normal so I have no clues

Comment: Query time is normal!
I guess my problem is related to DRF logic, not database ones.
but i cant find the solution.
i mean the process of finding and retrieving query set is important...